# Find the function f for $f$ be a function and $f(x) + f ( \frac{3x-1}{13x-4} ) = x$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

How to solve this algebraic functional equation?
Let $f$ be a function and $f(x) + f ( \frac{3x-1}{13x-4} ) = x$.
Find the function f, in terms of x.

Comment: @thanasissdr also $x\neq \frac{4}{13}$

Comment: Can you show us your own thoughts on this problem? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I've just finished the chapter of Funtions, and doing extra ones. I've never seen this kind of problems and no idea at all.

Comment: @thanasissdr your arithmetic has an error.

Comment: @Umberto I'm sorry but I typed wrong at first and I edited it later, so his comment doesn't work in this prob.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no general method. Functional equations are not solved at all unless you are lucky. This one can be solved because the function $3x-1\over13x-4$, when applied iteratively three times, returns x.

Using this fact, we may see:
$$f(x)+f\left({3x-1\over13x-4}\right)=x\tag1$$
$$f\left({3x-1\over13x-4}\right)+f\left({1-4x\over3-13x}\right)={3x-1\over13x-4}\tag2$$
$$f\left({1-4x\over3-13x}\right)+f(x)={1-4x\over3-13x}\tag3$$

Now add together the equations (1) and (3), subtract (2) and divide by 2 to get the formula you are after. When brought to the common denominator, it looks *wonderfully* cryptic:
$$f(x)={1\over2}\left(x-{3x-1\over13x-4}+{1-4x\over3-13x}\right)={169x^3-78x^2+5x+1\over338x^2-182x+24}$$

Comment: can you help me solve until the end please?

Comment: Thanks, @Ivan Neretin. I've now known that this kind of solving functional equations works for every function f such that f•f = f^-1.