# Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $x^2\cdot f(x)+f(1-x)=2x-x^4$ $\forall\; x\in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that: $\;x^2\cdot f(x)+f(1-x)=2x-x^4,\;\forall\; x\in \mathbb  R.$

**My solution:**
Replace $x$ by $(1-x)$ and by eliminating $f(1-x)$.

I obtained $f(x)=1-x^2$ as provided in my book.

**My doubt:**
How to check that there is no other function satisfying Above property?

Also, I think $f(x)=0,\;\forall\;x\in \mathbb R$ can be solution too.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: For the last question, you get $x^2\cdot 0+0=2x-x^4$. Left hand side is always zero, the right hand side is not always.

Comment: Your answer would be a correct answer if the right hand side of the functional equation were $2x^2-x^4$ rather than $2x-x^4$. It that a typo?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales No, there is no typo. $2x-x^4$ is correct. $x^2\cdot f(x)+f(1-x)$ $=x^2-x^4+1-(1-x)^2$ $=x^2-x^4+1-1+2x-x^2$ $=2x-x^4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is incomplete, because the solution is not required to be continuous. Your system of equations
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & 1 \\
1 & (1-x)^2 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
f(x) \\
f(1-x)
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
2x-x^4 \\
2(1-x) - (1-x)^4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has infinitely many solutions if $x=\varphi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or
$x=1-\varphi =\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. In this case, the matrix is not invertible, and we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f(\varphi) \\
f(1-\varphi)
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
-\varphi \\
\varphi-1
\end{pmatrix}
+\lambda 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
1+\varphi
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, the following is a valid solution:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1-x^2 & \text{ for } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\varphi, 1-\varphi\} \\
-\varphi -\lambda &  \text{ for } x=\varphi \\
\varphi-1 +\lambda(1+\varphi) &  \text{ for } x=1-\varphi
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: My doubt is How to check there can be more solution. How did you arrive at above thinking?  There are many questions like this they can have more than one answer but how to check them?

Comment: @mathophile There are no general answers that apply to all sorts of "find the function" questions. But in this particular case, it is just solving a system of two linear equations with two unknowns. Then we can use everything we know about systems of linear equations: In which case do they have exactly one solution, in which case do they have infinitely many (and what do they look like), in which case there is no solution at all? If there is exactly one solution for a given $x$, then you know your $f(x).$ Extra checking is needed for $x=\frac12$, because $f(x)=f(1-x)$ must hold in this case

Comment: Some more things come into play in this particular case: Replacing $x$ with $1-x$ is valid, because $1-x$ attains the same set of numbers as $x$, and this set is the domain of the function $f$. Such a replacement might be problematic if the set of reached numbers changes by this step, or the substitution leads to values outside of the function's domain.  Secondly, you do not introduce new solutions or take solutions away by rewriting the original problem as a system of two equations. Therefore, the number of solutions of the original problem matches the number of solution of the system of eqns